# Loading the same properties(yml) files in testing enviornment?

Tags: java, spring, configuration, yaml, spring-boot

I am trying to figure out whether I can load the same .yml property files in testing environment as I load in real.

For example I have a test:

```
\src\test\java\security\TokenTest.java
```

Annotated with:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
```

Then I have:

```
\src\main\resources\application.yml
```

When I run the application, the environment picks up property-source from the yml location.

Whenever I run my test, the environment does not see this file - i.e. property-source is not created/populated.

The obvious solution is to put duplicate file to the test location:

```
\src\test\resources\application.yml
```

And it will load, but that is bad - in terms that it raises unnecessary confusion when perceiving the difference between test and main resources.

This previous problem gets enhanced if you have configuration file per environment.

**Is there a way to load resources from src/main/resources for tests?**

This is probably some basic classpath scanning concept which I don't know.

My case is that I already faced the nightmare when you have 5 yml properties files per enviornment in src/main/resources and then you have 5 corresponding yml properties files in src/test/resources and someone from your team WILL 100 % at some point introduce discrepancy between them making everyone else bleed in the long term.

**So by any means tests must refer to the same configuration files not to be the lost within its own void context.**

**Solution: Try to "rebuild" the project.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to load resources from src/main/resources for tests?

It works for me. Maybe your IDE is not copying changes to the output directory on save or something (I have heard IntelliJ users have to switch that feature on)?

Comment: Could you explain further on setting up Intelli to support this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, but I figured out that it was a classpath problem in my run configuration in intellij, when setting that up like it should have been it worked as a charm loading application.yml from the main/resources.